# Where to find text in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I am trying to make changes to a site that is in Wordpress and the widget that I thing have the info I want to change a blank. I found the footer.php code in the editor put need help where the copyright text is. Where the code says ($data['copyright_text']), where do I find the copyright text?

```
<?php

global $data;

?>  
<?php
    if ( empty( $data['footer_show'] ) || (!empty( $data['footer_show'] ) && $data['footer_show'] == 'yes') ) { ?>
    <footer id="footer">
        <div class="container">

            <?php   
                if ( !empty ( $data['footer_row1_widget_positions'] ) ) {

                    if ( (!empty ( $data['footer_row1_show'] ) && $data['footer_row1_show'] == 'yes' ) || empty ( $data['footer_row1_show'] ) ) {

                        echo '<div class="row">';

                        $number_of_columns =    key( json_decode ( stripslashes ( $data['footer_row1_widget_positions'] ) ) );
                        $columns_array =        json_decode ( stripslashes ( $data['footer_row1_widget_positions'] ),true );

                        for ($i = 1; $i <= $number_of_columns; $i++) {
                            echo '<div class="span'.$columns_array[$number_of_columns][0][$i-1].'">';
                                if ( !dynamic_sidebar('Footer row 1 - widget '.$i.'') ) : endif; 
                            echo '</div>';
                        }

                        echo '</div><!-- end row -->';

                    }

                }

                if ( !empty ( $data['footer_row2_widget_positions'] ) ) {

                    if ( (!empty ( $data['footer_row2_show'] ) && $data['footer_row2_show'] == 'yes' ) || empty ( $data['footer_row2_show'] ) ) {

                        echo '<div class="row">';

                        $number_of_columns =    key( json_decode ( stripslashes ( $data['footer_row2_widget_positions'] ) ) );
                        $columns_array =        json_decode ( stripslashes ( $data['footer_row2_widget_positions'] ),true );

                        for ($i = 1; $i <= $number_of_columns; $i++) {
                            echo '<div class="span'.$columns_array[$number_of_columns][0][$i-1].'">';
                                if ( !dynamic_sidebar('Footer row 2 - widget '.$i.'') ) : endif; 
                            echo '</div>';
                        }

                        echo '</div><!-- end row -->';

                    }

                }
            ?>  

            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="bottom fixclear">

                    <?php
                        if ( isset( $data['footer_social_icons'] ) && is_array( $data['footer_social_icons'] ) && !empty ( $data['footer_social_icons'][0]['footer_social_icon'] ) ) {

                            $icon_class = '';


                            if( $data['footer_which_icons_set'] == 'colored' ) { 
                                $icon_class = 'colored';
                            }

                            echo '<ul class="social-icons '.$icon_class.' fixclear">';

                                echo '<li class="title">'.__('GET SOCIAL', THEMENAME ).'</li>'; // Translate

                                foreach ( $data['footer_social_icons'] as $key=>$icon ){

                                    $link = '';
                                    $target = '';

                                    if ( isset ( $icon['footer_social_link'] ) && is_array ( $icon['footer_social_link'] )) {
                                        $link = $icon['footer_social_link']['url'];
                                        $target = 'target="'.$icon['footer_social_link']['target'].'"';
                                    }


                                    echo '<li class="'.$icon['footer_social_icon'].'"><a href="" '.$target.'>'.$icon['footer_social_title'].'</a></li>';
                                }

                            echo '</ul>';

                        }
                    ?>

                    <?php if( $data['copyright_text'] || $data['footer_logo']  ) { ?>

                        <div class="copyright">


                            <?php 
                                if( $data['footer_logo'] ) {
                                    echo '<a href="'.home_url().'"><img src="'.$data['footer_logo'].'" alt="" /></a>';

                                } 

                                if( $data['copyright_text'] ) {
                                    echo '<p>'.stripslashes($data['copyright_text']).'</p>';

                                } 
                            ?>


                        </div><!-- end copyright -->

                    <?php } ?>


                    </div><!-- end bottom -->
                </div>
            </div><!-- end row -->

        </div>
    </footer>
    <?php } ?>
    </div><!-- end page_wrapper -->

    <a href="#" id="totop"><?php echo __('TOP', THEMENAME ); ?></a> <?php // Translate ?>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see what the current copyright text is, you can stick `echo $data['copyright_text'];` anywhere after declaring `global $data;`.

To delete it, you can do `$data['copyright_text'] = null;` or `$data['copyright_text'] = '';`

Comment: How do I edit the 'copyright_text' where is it pulling it from in wordpress?

Comment: With global variables like that, it's hard to tell where it came from. If you download the whole site on your computer, you can try searching the files for "$data['copyright_text']" to try and find it, but it might be hard to find.  Either way, you've already found where `$data['copyright_text']` is used, so you can just edit that variable right there before it is used on the page.

Answer (score -1):

Be careful of changing your theme like this.  If you have a theme that has a commercial License, you may get into trouble for removing the Licencees copyright and trademark.

If you've created the theme yourself however, then it should be placed in the footer file in a place that is appropriate to the design of the theme.

Comment: The copyright is for company on the site, not for the theme.

Comment: @J.Musser Yes, it's comment. But stupid SO rules not allowed write comments without reputation.. Something like that...